# Modify Columns Repeated Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table with columns repeated and not repeated.

```
{
"Id": "0",
"textField": [
  "value1",
  "value2",
  "value3"
],
"numericField": [
  "10"
],
"dateField": "2016-02-24 15:48:00 UTC"
}

Id              INTEGER     REQUIRED
textField       STRING      REPEATED
numericField    INTEGER     REPEATED
dateField       TIMESTAMP   NULLABLE
```

But the "textField" field must be REPEATED and the "numericField" field must be no REPEATED.

I tryed to copy the information into another table with the changed fields but this replaces my fields and let me fields REPEATED
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#copyingtable

I tryed to create a table from a query but I do not know how to define the query so that the "textField" field that is "REPEATED" does not change and the "numericField" becomes into not REPEATED.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.query.tableDefinitions

how do I change the field without losing information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a query using the [`FLATTEN`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#flatten) function and by turning off query result auto-flattening.

```
SELECT Id, textField, numericField, dateField 
FROM FLATTEN([dataset.table], numericField);
```

You can turn off auto-flattening of query results which will preserve the repeatedness of textField.  In the query configuration, set [`allowLargeResults`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.query.allowLargeResults) to true and [`flattenResults`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.query.flattenResults) to false.  Both of these options are available in the web UI or bq CLI by similar names.

**Caveat:** If you have multiple numericField values in a row, this will result in a cross-product expansion of rows (e.g. one output row per numericField value in each input row).  This may or may not be a problem for you (your example row doesn't have multiple numericField values), and may or may not be what you're looking to do.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!!